# QGIS 3 crashes on opening file dialog

Tags: error, qgis-3

I cannot get QGIS 3 to work. I've filed bug report #19629 but thought I'd also ask here to see if anyone has had this problem as it may just be my installation.

This is on Windows 10.
I have uninstalled all versions of QGIS and renamed the .qgis2 directory and then reinstalled v3.2.1 with the standalone installer.

- Start QGIS 3.2.1
- click the "Open Shapefile Layer" toolbar button
- QGIS opens the "New Shapefile Layer" dialog
- click the "..." button next to the File Name input
- QGIS opens a "Save Layer As" dialog and immediately CRASHES to the "Oh Uh!" dialog

It also crashes if I start the program and click the "Open Project" button.
QGIS opens "Choose a QGIS Project File to Open" dialog and then crashes to the "Oh Uh!" dialog with no further input from me.

None of these crashes have anything to do with data. I never get to select a file.

QGIS v2.18 works but I'd like to try v3.   :)

Comment: I tried again by uninstalling and deleting everything related to QGIS including the registry entries. Reinstall still crashes after the file dialog opens.  Something is wrong on my system.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution yet on this computer... I have QGIS running on a different Windows 10 computer.  I cannot find the difference which causes the problem.